# Do you use Blend to fill the WPF Views with controls or do it manually?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, blend

I've to draw a lot of UI Views on a WPF project. Normally I perform myself the Grid   division in rows /columns but I was wondering if it's OK to "drag the controls" from Blend on the designer and leave all those absolute fixing.

In this way I can parallel my job using another person that's not a dev to write the views.

Anyone used blend for such a scope or everyone split the ui in row/columns?

Thanks

Comment: If "absolute fixing" means layout by Margins, with all elements in a single Grid cell or Canvas, that's horrible. How would you ever implement a useful resizing behavior?

Comment: Don't drag controls in the designer. Type them in as xaml. Your layout risks only working on just your pc otherwise. If your layout doesn't "flow" then you could well find it doesn't all fit on a user's screen. Even if they run maximised.  Fixed margins which are single digit px are ok, anything bigger is something you should think twice about.

Comment: I know this, and I agrre with you, till now I've done so... but since I've to write a lot of views and I can have another person (not a dev) to "draw" them, I was wondering if I have to teach him to define rows/cols of Grid